# Normalize values in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

What I need is normalize the rating column below by the following process:

1. Group by user field id.
2. Find mean rating for each user.
3. Locate each users review tip and subtract the user's mean rating.

I have this data frame:

```
                user       rating
 review_id
         a      1          5
         b      2          3
         c      1          3
         d      1          4
         e      3          4
         f      2          2
...
```

I then calculate the mean for each user:

```
 >>>data.groupby('user').rating.mean()

 user
 1       4
 2       2.5
 3       4
```

I need the final result to be:

```
                user       rating
 review_id
         a      1          1
         b      2          0.5
         c      1          -1
         d      1          0
         e      3          0
         f      2          -0.5
...
```

How can dataframes provide this kind of functionality efficiently?

Comment: Are you sure the values in the rating columns are numeric?  Try `data['rating'] = data.rating.astype('int')` and then run your groupby.

Comment: @Alexander yeap that was it.

Comment: @binarysubstrate Take this with a grain of salt because I am new to pandas. I think this thread you posted normalizes each row with a static value so I guess I want a different type of normalization.

Comment: Fair enough. I removed my comment, but it turns out there's no way to retract a flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a `groupby().transform()`, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation

In this case, grouping by `'user'`, and then for each group subtract the mean of that group (the function you supply to `transform` is applied to each group, but the result keeps the original index):

```
In [7]: data.groupby('user').transform(lambda x: x - x.mean())
Out[7]:
           rating
review_id
a             1.0
b             0.5
c            -1.0
d             0.0
e             0.0
f            -0.5
```